# Finding count and existence of ID

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query that combines finding a particular record (identified by primary key) having its `status` column set to `CONFIRMED` but can also find whether that primary key exists in the table at all. This is what I tried:

```
SELECT 
count(`p2`.`id`) AS `confirmed`,
count(`p1`.`id`) AS `exists`
FROM `foos` `p2`, `foos` p1`
WHERE
`p2`.`id` = 28 AND 
`p2`.`status` = 'CONFIRMED' AND
`p1`.`id` = 28
```

So again, I'm trying to find if there exists a `foo` with `id = 28` and `status = 'CONFIRMED'` but I also want to know whether the id doesn't exist or whether it does exist but the `status` isn't `confirmed`. MySQL says there's a problem with this query near

```
`p2`.`id` = 28 AND 
`p2`.`status` = 'CONFIRMED'
```

Is this query possible at all?

Comment: You seem to be missing one backtick before `p1` in the `FROM` statement.

Comment: Facepalm. Thanks. But it still doesn't work logically. The output I get is :

Comment: confirmed: 0, exists: 0; I expected confirmed: 0, exists: 1. Is my query logically wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would solve it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(a1.id) AS EXISTS, 
       IF(status = 'CONFIRMED', 1, 0) AS confirmed 
FROM   foo f1 
       LEFT JOIN foo f2 
         ON f1.id = f2.id 
WHERE  f1.id = 28
```

Comment: I realised that there's no need to do a JOIN, the following should work the same: `SELECT COUNT(id) AS e, IF(status = 'CONFIRMED', 1, 0) AS confirmed FROM foo WHERE id = 28;`

Comment: I ended up doing something else: "SELECT `id`, `status` FROM `foo` WHERE `id` = 28 LIMIT 1" :P. Empty resultset means id doesn't exist, otherwise, I can check the status column in the resultset. But yours is a pure MySQL solution and so was the right answer  as per the question I asked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using subqueries, this would be a solution:

```
SELECT count(p1.id) AS 'confirmed', 
  (SELECT count(p2.id) 
  FROM foos p2
  WHERE p2.id = 28) AS 'exists'
FROM foos p1 
WHERE p1.id = 28 AND p2.status = 'CONFIRMED';
```